# Creating Grails shared libraries

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I'm working on a multi-module project right now, where most of the modules are designed to have their own Web interface (REST API, Web pages, etc.) done using Grails. There are a few classes that I want to be utilized by different (all) modules. If this were a straightforward Java project, I would just create a new Maven project (using `archetype:generate`), deploy/install, and just import it on the modules accordingly. How do I do this with Grails? Is this one of the things Grails plugins are meant to address?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are talking about a jar/lib artifact it would be best to use a local Maven repository where you build your maven project to then resolve it as a dependency for your modules within your `BuildConfig.groovy`.

Nothing is stopping you from using a Grails plugin to provide this resource, but that seems a bit overkill since Grails plugins are intended to do so much more.

Comment: That's an option, but the problem is that some of the common/utility classes use some Grails specific features. For example, I created some testing components that use the default Spock stack in Grails, that I want to reuse on other Grails projects.

Comment: Well if it can be distributed as a jar then you should do so as a jar, otherwise a Grails plugin makes more sense. Without knowing your requirements it's hard to say much more.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that you want to have a multi-project build or a Mavenized Grails project or separate plugins.

**Use a Grails multi-project-build**

- Guide: http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/ref/Command%20Line/create-multi-project-build.html

**Straight Maven integration**

- Guide : http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/commandLine.html#antAndMaven
- I have a basic introduction video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tqGN61hiciE

**Separate Grails plugins**

You could still use separate Grails plugins and reference them in your main application.